# Plotting robot path and orientation using python +/- matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have a 1000 x 3 numpy array of coordinates that consist of an (x, y, theta in radians) pose for a moving robot at various times (from time = 0 to time = 1000).  Is it possible to graph this position and orientation information using python so that at each point (x,y) there is a small arrow that points in the theta direction? Perhaps a matplotlib type graph would be possible for this?

Comment: Check out `plt.quiver`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the arrow function in `matplotlib` ([documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html))?

Assuming that theta is angle in radians from the x axis, perhaps something like the following for each point will do it.

```py
arrow(x, y, cos(theta), sin(theta))
```

The above code will draw an arrow from (x,y) to (x+dx, y+dy).

Another option is `matplotlib.pyplot.quiver`[documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html). The `quiver` function allows us to control the length of the arrow in many ways.